# How to enable/disable primefaces commandButton?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

I have two buttons on screen. When page first loaded I want to button2 is disabled until button1 is clicked. 
When button1 is clicked, button2 must be enabled.

I tried:

```xhtml
<p:commandButton value="Normalize"
    actionListener="#{mainTable.normalize}" update="dataTable"
    id="normalize" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"
    style="font-size: 14px">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}"
        target="#{mainTable.disable}" />
</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton value="To Verify Next->" action="verify.xhtml"
    actionListener="#{mainTable.verify}" id="next"
    styleClass="ui-priority-primary" style="font-size: 14px"
    disabled="#{!(bean.disable)}">
</p:commandButton>
```

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MainTable
{

    private boolean disable;

    public MainTable()
    {
        disable = false;
    }
    public boolean isDisable()
    {
        return disable;
    }

    public void setDisable(boolean disable)
    {
        this.disable = disable;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. When I clicked button1, button2 is still disabled.
What is wrong?

Comment: Debug your code. Is the `disable` property being set? Also why are you using `f:setPropertyActionListener` tag when you have the `normalize` action listener? Just set it to true when `normalize` is called.

Comment: I reproduced your code and it's perfectly working for me.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I tried it also ( setting it in normalize method) but it is not working also.

Comment: Sorry it is about line:   
disabled="#{!(bean.disable)}">
it should be mainTable.disable
Problem solved.

Comment: Glad to see it worked. Try to publish an answer for your own question instead of editing the question itself to publish the answer there.

Comment: I think instead of `disabled="#{!(myTable.disable)}">` you mean `disabled="#{!(mainTable.disable)}">`?  If that's the case, you might edit the question, or add your own answer and accept that one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about thoughtfulness mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Try to update the second button on clicking the first one like the `dataTable`

---

You should replace the `bean` in `disabled="#{!(bean.disable)}">` with `mainTable` => `disabled="#{!(mainTable.disable)}">`

Comment: Any error message?

Maybe try to wrap the two buttons in a container like the primefaces outputPanel (`p:outputPanel`)

Comment: Did my answer helped you? I see you solved it, but without updating the button it shouln't be working.

Answer (score 1):

You should swap 2 buttons in a Outputpanel, and update this outputpanel alter for next button, like this:

```
<p:outputPanel id="pnltest">
  <p:commandButton value="Normalize"
    actionListener="#{mainTable.normalize}" update="dataTable,pnltest"
    ...
  </p:commandButton>
  <p:commandButton value="To Verify Next->" action="verify.xhtml"
    actionListener="#{mainTable.verify}" id="next"
    ...
  </p:commandButton>
<p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: How is this supposed to solve it? This issue is not related with `rendered` attribute, but with `disabled` one.

Comment: @XtremeBiker This is my experience, and it works fine for some project :-)

Comment: @XtremeBiker in some cases, OP example is work fine, but some cases i must do as i answer.

Comment: But you're updating the whole panel when there's no need to do it... Just updating the target command button should work.

Comment: @İlknurKabadayı Your code and my code are work fine, i have just tested!

Comment: @İlknurKabadayı I don't know your environment, i tested with liferay 6.1.2 in portlet environment.

Comment: Thanks @RongNK, problem is my negligence.